# .htaccess - redirect every URL except for one

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, frameworks

I'm working on a website built upon a custom PHP framework and I'm having a little trouble with the .htaccess file. I need to integrate this website with Wordpress, so when someone enters www.example.com/blog it must go to the Wordpress. Right now, the framework is redirecting like this:

```
http://www.example.com/blog => http://www.example.com/index.php?url=blog
```

How can I update the .htaccess file to prevent this specific redirection?
Thanks a lot.

By the way, here is the only rule within this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you show us the .htaccess file?

Comment: I added the only rule in that file above, ok?

Comment: @ficuscr if I remove it, then no redirection will be made. I want only that Blog redirection to be prevented. Got it?

Comment: So the redirect you describe as being in place, and the rewrite rule you've shared don't seem related. Maybe there are other redirects in apache's `<Directory` or `<Location` blocks? Still confused if you are trying to remove something or add a rule which supersedes. Is wordpress on whole other domain/subdomain, not clear on that either?

Comment: What is in 'public' directory?

Comment: I see. Let me try to make it clearer. Forget about the rest. The thing is: that rule is redirecting  everything from /root folder to /root/public folder. And I want it to be kept like that, except when someone enters www.example.com/blog. This moment, I dont want the rule to redirect to /root/public folder. I want this URL to go to /root/blog folder. I hope it helps now :P

Comment: @splash58 frontend stuff, only.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` ?

Comment: @splash58 still not working, but thanks for the help.

Comment: try without the end sign `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`